# I am missing the Issue tracking list, do I need to activate some feature?

Tags: issue-tracking

I am using sp2013. I have created a new website and selected the projecttemplate. When I go to site content I miss some OOTB lists:

> Issue Tracking
>
> Links

Do I need to activate some features which are generate this lists? When I click on "Add an app" I can create by my self a new links or issue tracking list. But I was expecting OOTB these lists are created.

[image]

Like you see below, the feature is already activated.
[image]

I hope you understand my question. Because when I click on add new app it is possible to add these lists. But I was expecting them OOTB in my site content.
[image]
Do you have these lists OOTB already created in your site content? Please make a printscreen of your site content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just created a new site collection with the project template, and as you mention the 2 list are not added by default. Add the lists and you get them as web parts.

If you ever are missing out any of the lists, just activate the Team collaboration list feature.

Team collaboration lists provide the following:

**Libraries**

- Form Library
- Picture Library
- Document Library

**Lists**

- Announcements
- Calendar
- Contacts
- Custom List
- Custom List with DataSheet view
- Discussion board
- External List
- Issue tracking list
- Links
- Project List
- Survey
- Tasks

Comment: I did check if the team collaboration lists feature was activated or not. It was already activated. But see printscreen in my update, for the only lists I have.

Comment: Yes, in a project template its activated by default.

Comment: could you please add a printscreen how your site content looks after activate this "team collaboration lists" feature? I realy appriciate it if you can do that.

Comment: Activating the feature only gives you the option to choose from more different list templates while creating a new list, it does not add any lists to site content by itself.

Comment: Hope it clears things up a bit. :)